# Symfony2.8 Form submit

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

I have problem submitting my form, i cannot find the solution any help ? I am trying to display the form and submit it in the same action but my form is not submitted totally, i have got post request populated in (symfony-profile) but it is not flush to DB. And of course NO ERROR message.

Here is how i render the form:

```
{{render(controller('ApxDevMessageBundle:Message:new', { 'product' : entity.id }))}}
```

Controller to take care of display and handle:

```
 /**
 * Display the form and Handle it
 * Not route needed 
 */
public function  newAction(Request $request, Products $product)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $message = new MessageMap();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($message);

    $product = $em->getRepository('ApxDevUsersBundle:Products')->find($product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $data = $form->getData();
            //var_dump($data);die; (not work)

            $product = $em->getRepository('ApxDevUsersBundle:Products')->find($product);

            if($user->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
            {
                $message->setFromID($user->getUserInfo());
            }else{
                $message->setEmail($data->get('email'));
            }

            $message->setToID($product->getUserInfo());
            $em->persist($message);
            $em->flush();

            $x = $product->getCity();
            $city = $em->getRepository('ApxDevPagesBundle:City')->findOneby(array('libelle' => trim($x)));

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('warning', $this->get('translator')->trans('product.create_first'));
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home_show', array('entity' => $product, 'city' => $city)));
        }
    return $this->render('ApxDevMessageBundle:Message:modules/email.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thanks for your help

Nic

Comment: Are you sure the form is valid?

Comment: Yes i am pretty sure because i have got the data on "symfony profile" "POST PARAMETER", after the first request and when the page is first loaded POST PARAMETER  is empty.      I think it might be the fact that i am using twig render(controller) with the same action or i don't know.

Comment: can you try to exit in your isValid() and also add isSubmitted?

Comment: When i try $request->getMethod('POST'), i got the $message object when i var_dump die, but it is empty objet. I don 't think this has something to do but i using Modal Bootstrap for the form

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong direction, your are trying to proof that you have a post request which I do not doubt. I think the problem is in the form not being valid, therefore I want you to make sure your form is valid. and by valid I mean that the form is submitted but with errors

Comment: {{form_start(form_message) }}
     {% if form_message.email is defined %} <label>Email&nbsp;:</label>
     {{ form_widget(form_message.email) }} {% endif %}
     <label>Subjet&nbsp;:</label>
     {{ form_widget(form_message.messageID.subject) }}
     <label>Message&nbsp;:</label>
     {{ form_widget(form_message.messageID.message) }}<br />
     {{ form_widget(form_message.submit) }}
    {{form_end(form_message)}}

Comment: Just test the code without render(controller) and put the form in separate pages it works just fine as expected, but it has to go in modal view

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your render / submit function does not have all steps that are needed in a form submission. For an instance *`isValid()`* on its own is not sufficient, you are missing *`isSubmitted()`*

> isSubmitted() : Returns whether the form is submitted. 
>   [API Documentation for isSubmitted()](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_isSubmitted)

Take a look at the form submission example given in Symfony documentation. [Link to Syfmony2.8 form submission](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html#handling-form-submissions), I have extracted some code for you.

Have a look at the code below,

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $message = new MessageMap();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($message);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    }

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I hope this helps,